# A man buys 2 watches for Rs. 560. He sells one at 15% profit and other at 10% loss. He neither gains nor loses. What is the cost of the 2 watches?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man purchases 2 watches for Rs. 560. He sells one at $15$% profit and other at $10$% loss. He neither gains nor loses. What is the cost price of the two watches?

The correct answer is Rs. $224$ and Rs. $336$
 What I did:-
Let Cost price of first watch is x and cost price of second watch be 560-x
S.P of first watch= 1.15x
S.P of second watch= 0.90(560-x)
Since there is no profit and no loss, then difference between cost price and selling price will be zero
 $540-1.15x-495+0.9x=0$
x came out to be 260 and 300.
What is wrong in my way? Let me know please

Answer (score 0):

I think you generally have the right idea.  But the equation should be:

$560-(1.15x+504-.9x)=0$

Comment: Thanks, I made such a stupid mistake @paw88789